# iOS: alpha relating visual effect

Tags: ios, interface-builder, alpha

My goal is to achieve something like this.

[image]

There is a background, above the background I added a view with an alpha set to 0.9 and background set to black. The bubbles are UIButtons, and I want to highlight them when they are clicked. But I don't know how to because these buttons' alpha is 1. Only their parent view's alpha is modified to 0.9.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20424014/2710486).

Try set the alpha of the black background to 0.9 instead of the alpha for the view, something like `view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)`

Then depending on the highlight selection of button, set the alpha accordingly.